# How can I simulate the use of a casino bonus n number of times

Tags: statistics, variance, simulation

If I have a free £50 casino bonus that has to be wagered 40x (£2000 total), and I use the bonus on a game with a return to player of 95% and medium variance using £1 spins/games. Is there a way I can randomly simulate this 'n' number of times to get the amount earned from the payout each time?

For example, if n=1, then the simulation may give me a value of £75.11. If n=3, I may get £0, £13.12 and £0 and if n=1000, I would get 1000 random results, and the average might be £3.75 say. I know more often than not you would end up with £0, but I want to make a simulator so I can calculate the average you can expect to make if you did this 1,000,000 times for example. The value has to be something > 0, as you can't go below 0, because it's a free bonus. Also, how would the 'return to player', 'variance' and 'spin/stake size' of the game you're playing be incorporated into this simulator?

I want the simulator to be as random as if you actually played out the bonus on a casino site yourself.

Any questions please let me know.

Comment: What does "medium variance" mean? What are the actual bets, payoffs and their probabilities?

Comment: I'm not sure how others are building their simulators, here's an example of one online http://www.beatingbonuses.com/simulator.htm. What is the maths behind building something like this? I don't understand how they've built this?

Comment: It is easy to write a program that simulates random events, like tossing a die or dealing 5 cards from a randomly shuffled deck. But you cannot get something out of nothing. If you want to simulate what *happens* with those dice or cards, you need to write down the rules that tell what happens: for example, when does player A get money and how much. Simulating a game that involves human actions (perhaps by opponents) is even harder because you have to somehow model what they will do in particular situations. Asking just "simulate something, I don't know what" is simply an impossible deal.

Comment: I understand how to input the rules of roulette and blackjack for the simulator to work? But how do they do this with slot, with different variances and rtp's? That's what I don't know how to do